# the problem is writing data to specific cells and file is corrupted

Tags: c++, mfc

It is not easy 1. to write data to specific cells (excel file) and 2. excel file is corrupted after writing, saving, copying 
(use visual C++ 6.0 on windows OS 7)

//input row data excel(specific cell like B6~B8,B11...)

```
CString strOneRecord = null;
for( pos = strList.GetHeadPosition(); pos != posTail; )
{
  CString str = recordList.GetNext( pos );
  strOneRecord += str;
  strOneRecord += szSeparator; 
  strOneRecord += "\t";
}
```

//file saving and copy new file

```
archiveContent.WriteString(strOneRecord);
archiveContent.Close();
filePersistent.Close(); 
CopyFile(FALSE);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2xRS.gif)

Comment: I have no idea what the code presented has to do with Excel or writing an old .xls excel file.

Comment: The file .xls file format is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve by excel9.h

```
    CString sSub;
    BOOL    blNewXls = FALSE;
    int nCol;
    int nSheetNum;
    int nCnt;
    CString strSerialNo,strInspector;

    COleVariant VOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);    
    _Application objApp;
    _Workbook objBook;
    Workbooks objBooks;
    Worksheets objSheets;
    _Worksheet objSheet;
    Range objRange;
    Font ft;
    LPDISPATCH lpDisp;

    if( !objApp.CreateDispatch("Excel.Application") ){AfxMessageBox("XLS ERROR");   return FALSE;}
    objApp.SetVisible(TRUE);
    objApp.SetUserControl(TRUE);
    lpDisp = objApp.GetWorkbooks();
    objBooks.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

   lpDisp = objBooks.Open(destFileName, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional,VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional);
   objBook.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);
   lpDisp = objBook.GetSheets();
   objSheets.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

   lpDisp = objSheets.GetItem(COleVariant((long)1));
   objSheet.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

    objRange = objSheet.GetRange(COleVariant("C2"), COleVariant("C2")); 
    //excel cell number
    sSub.Format("%s", row[0]);
    objRange.SetValue(COleVariant(CString(sSub)));
```